Uninstalling Microsoft Office, which isn't installed
My Dell G5 comes pre-installed with some sort of trial/partial version of Office. (Opening it requires me to enter a license key, which I don't have.)
Evidence that office is installed:

Click start > type "office" and Excel, Powerpoint, and Outlook show up
Double-clicking a .csv file opens it in Excel
The presence of the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office folder, which contains root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE

But, I can't uninstall it. It's not present under:

Start > Add or remove programs > Search apps > searching for office or excel shows nothing
If I click on Related settings > System Components, searching, again, yields nothing

I'm tempted to simply track down the start-menu shortcuts and nuke the directories/files entirely, although I'm unsure if that will leave behind traces in my registry or otherwise break things.
How can I uninstall Office?
(Third-party uninstallers like Revo are welcome, if they will remove it.)

Turns out it was listed under Add or Remove Programs as "Microsoft 365." Uninstalling this shows a window that it's uninstalling Office:

